# consume int result returned from stored procedure in MVC4

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[takeOrder]
(
    @id int = 0,
    @userid int = 0,
    @diningid int,
    @amount float
)
as
begin
    declare @countt as int

    select @countt = COUNT(*) 
    from Order_master 
    where dining_Id = @diningid and isActive = 1

    if @countt <> 0
    begin
        update Order_master 
        set amount = @amount 
        where dining_Id = @diningid and isActive = 1;
    end
    else
    begin
        insert into Order_master(userid, dining_Id, amount, [date], isActive)
        values (@userid, @diningid, @amount, GETDATE(), 1)
    end

    --select amount from Order_master where dining_Id=@diningid and isActive=1
    select oid 
    from Order_master 
    where dining_Id = @diningid and isActive = 1
end
```

In controller I am trying to get return result as mention below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult takeOrder(Order_master order,List<Menu_info> menu)
{
            String msg = "";
            int oid;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    Order_master objOreder = new Order_master
                    {
                        amount = order.amount,
                        isActive = 1,
                        date = order.date,
                        dining_Id = order.dining_Id,
                        userId = order.userId
                    };
                   object orderId = db.takeOrder(objOreder.oid, objOreder.userId, objOreder.dining_Id, objOreder.amount);                                     
                   oid = (int)orderId;
                   msg = "success..!!";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    msg = "error...";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                msg = "please provide info";
            }

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return new JsonResult { Data = msg, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
}
```

But it returns an exception

> Cannot convert type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult' to 'int'

I am not able to get single return value from stored procedure.

Hope I get the right solution.

Comment: Try to use: `oid = orderId.FirstOrDefault<int>();`. The `ObjectResult<T>` can have multiple values - you need to ask for the first `int` to get the result back

Answer (score 0):

```
object orderId = db.takeOrder(objOreder.oid, objOreder.userId, objOreder.dining_Id, objOreder.amount);                                     
oid = (int)orderId;
```

Try this conversion method.

```
oid = Convert.ToInt32(orderId);
```

Comment: it gives Exception as : "{System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value)
  "

Answer (score 0):

You can use like

```
 public int InsertWebProperty(int orgid, int? userid, string address, string property_Id, string latitude, string longitude, int? compamyid)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32((db.InsertWebProperty(orgid, userid, address, property_Id, latitude, longitude, 0)).FirstOrDefault().recidentity.Value);
    }
```

Please let me know if it not worked for you..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*db.TakeOrder().FirstOrDefault().ToString()*  = One value returned as a string

*db.TakeOrder().FirstOrDefault().ToList()* = Row returned as a list.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create view as

   CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vScalar]
   AS
   SELECT '' AS Value
2. In Stored Procedure return

   SELECT CAST(orderId AS VARCHAR(10)) AS value
3. In Entity Framework, set function return use entity vScalar
4. In code

   vScalar orderId = db.takeOrder(objOreder.oid, objOreder.userId, objOreder.dining_Id, objOreder.amount).FirstOrDefault;

   oid = (int)orderId.value;