# Not able to convert object of type {System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<int>} to int - ASP MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The stored procedure output gives me an integer value. I need to pass that value to the view page and increment it.

Controller:

```
var OrderId = db.USP_SEL_LAST_ORDERID();
ViewData["OrderId"] = (OrderId);
```

View:

```
var orderid = int.Parse(@ViewBag.OrderId);
```

Error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Is this question about the error? If so, is it not self explanatory?

Comment: yes. I need to know how to convert this object type of {System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<int>} to int 32.

Comment: I don't think that's your problem here. the int.Parse method will return you an int.. Look at the error message...its the type that you are passing into the parse method that is wrong.

Comment: then how should i cast ViewBag item, which is of object type to int?

Comment: Ok.. see answer below

Answer (score 0):

@Wheels73's answer is almost right, however you need to know that stored procedure method returns data from `DbContext` in form of result set, even it has only single value. You can use either `FirstOrDefault()` or `FirstOrDefault<int>()` method to ensure it returns `int`:

**Controller**

```
var OrderId = db.USP_SEL_LAST_ORDERID().FirstOrDefault();
ViewData["OrderId"] = OrderId; // ensure this is an integer
```

**View**

```
var orderid = int.Parse(@ViewBag.OrderId.ToString());
```

Note that `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<T>` can have multiple values (with different data types), hence it is possible to ask for first `int` to get SP result. Also, better to use strongly-typed viewmodel class with `int` property rather than dynamic `ViewBag` or `ViewData`:

Model

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult ActionName()
{
    var model = new ViewModel();
    var OrderId = db.USP_SEL_LAST_ORDERID().FirstOrDefault();
    model.OrderId = OrderId;

    // returns entire viewmodel to view, 'int.Parse' conversion not required
    return View(model); 
}
```

Similar issue:

[consume int result returned from stored procedure in MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054819/consume-int-result-returned-from-stored-procedure-in-mvc4)

[How to handle ObjectResult in Entity Framework 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654365/how-to-handle-objectresult-in-entity-framework-4)

Answer (score -1):

See below.

```
  var orderid = int.Parse(@ViewBag.OrderId.ToString());
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help. But still am getting error :Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Do you actually have anything in the ViewBag.OrderID. This works locally for me.

Comment: Yeah i do have. SP returns 0 and that been assigned to ViewBag.

Comment: May I ask why you are using ViewBag and not a View model?

Comment: I presume you set viewbag in the controller like this. ViewBag.OrderID = X

Comment: Am actually returning multiple result sets via 3 different viewbags and one among those is for OrderId
Yeah i tried ViewBag.OrderId = value. Still the same

Comment: Well if you scrap the use of the view bag and create a strongly typed view model, then you wont have to worry about converting data types or using the view bag and the error will go. However, the fact that the error now says that the input string is not in the correct format still means that there is a problem with the value in orderid.  Remove the parse from the code and just assign it to orderid, add a break point, step into it and see what happens